# Distorted Image

Tags: graphics

I am using LaTeX to write my master thesis. And I cannot add any file to the document. I am doing the same thing, I have been doing before, but my images become distorted after compiling. Can anyone tell me why is this happening? Thanks.

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}        

\includegraphics[height=10cm,width=15cm,scale=1]{Secondary1}
\caption{Creating Frequency Difference Using Only One Oscillator}

\includegraphics[height=5cm,width=7cm,scale=1.5]{Secondary2}
\caption{Creating Frequency Difference Using Only One Oscillator}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Not sure this is related, but you cannot have two images with their caption inside a single figure environment. Also, don't use the `center` environment in a figure, you'll have too large vertical spacing. Use the `\centering` directive instead.

Comment: You are overdoing with the \includegraphics options. Decide if you want to set the width, height or scale.

Comment: @Bernard yes you can have two captions in a figure. Try it out.

Comment: I have done the two caption thing before. And even now I have both the images. Just they are completely distorted.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: !!! That goes against everything I thought. Isn't \caption associated to an environment counter?

Comment: @Bernard the caption itself increases the counter (that's why \label has to be after the \caption).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I thought it was entering the figure environment which increased the counter.

Comment: I also tried deleting one caption, still same

Comment: Is the aspect ratio of the figure originally 5:7? try just writing `\includegraphics{secondary1}` and see how that looks, if the image is too big/small, try `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{secondary1}`

Comment: @SarahKhan Ignore Bernard's comment. It is wrong. Your problem are the includegraphics options. If you set both height and width it will distort the graphic.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did as you suggested. The problem remains. But this time there is no image, only a blank box with the caption.png

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen I put no aspect ratio and deleted the center option. But it still shows an error and says file not found. And in the pdf, there is only a black box with the option

Comment: \begin{figure}[!h]

\includegraphics{new setup1}
\caption{Creating Frequency Difference Using Only One Oscillator}

\end{figure}                                   I put this. And nothing!

Comment: @SarahKhan  If, you set `width` or `height`, then `scale` is ignored and the image is scaled proportionally until that lenght. If you set  `width` and `height`, the image will have just that width and height, whatever the original dimensions, except   if you add the option `keepaspectratio`. Then  the image is scaled proportionally until reach the width or the height, but hardly both.  With respect your last comment: Do not use spaces in file names, and your life will be easier.

Comment: only have one of height, width and scale, if you have all three you are specifying that the figure should be distorted.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help.